# Web scraping using Python, bs4, requests - returns None or [] instead of data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from this URL:

https://www.airbnb.co.in/rooms/19065198?adults=1&children=0&enable_m3_private_room=true&infants=0&pets=0&check_in=2023-08-26&check_out=2023-08-31&source_impression_id=p3_1691051413_KTDrMOMv8%2BRURWL2&previous_page_section_name=1000&federated_search_id=ecffe6fa-bab8-4775-871a-c287ea9a6105

And want to retrieve the listing title

[image]

However, it returns [] instead of the title.

I tried extracting using the class name, the tag, etc. still same result

Code line :

```
url = "https://www.airbnb.co.in/rooms/578733555164036351?adults=1&children=0&enable_m3_private_room=true&infants=0&pets=0&check_in=2023-08-03&check_out=2023-08-10&source_impression_id=p3_1691051413_IRUCgeLp3DTnpRX4&previous_page_section_name=1000&federated_search_id=ecffe6fa-bab8-4775-871a-c287ea9a6105"

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

print(soup.select('[elementtiming=LCP-target]'))
```

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Have you actually inspected `res.text` to ensure the markup you get from the server matches your expectation? It's well known that Airbnb (a) uses preventative measures to prevent this type of scraping, and (b) relies heavily on JavaScript to create their front end views, which doesn't get evaluted/executed by `requests`.

Comment: @esqew I think you are right about this. I checked it and it doesn't look quite as expected. Do you know any alternate way to do this other than using requests ?

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the page, you will see that the data is loaded *dynamically* within a `<script>` tag.

All the data is in JSON format on the page, so you can convert it to a Python `dict` and access the `listingTitle` key which contains the desired title.

However, since there's a lot of data, the simplest solution would be to just use `requests` and the `re` modules the find the `listingTitle` key and then get the data
:

```py
import requests
import re


URL = "https://www.airbnb.co.in/rooms/19065198?adults=1&children=0&enable_m3_private_room=true&infants=0&pets=0&check_in=2023-08-26&check_out=2023-08-31&source_impression_id=p3_1691051413_KTDrMOMv8%2BRURWL2&previous_page_section_name=1000&federated_search_id=ecffe6fa-bab8-4775-871a-c287ea9a6105"

response = requests.get(URL)

print(re.search('"listingTitle":(.*?),', response.text).group(1))
```

Prints:

```
"Lost&Found Galactic Friends' House"
```